# ASP.Net Classic Serilog not writing to file

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net, serilog

I am trying to create an ilogger with unity and I have it created fine but when I invoke the logger, nothing is written to the file.
What am I missing?

This is my unity

```
container.RegisterType<ILogger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory((ctr, type, name) => {

ILogger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.Enrich.WithThreadId()
.Enrich.WIthProperty("ApplicationVersion", GetApplicationVersion())
.WriteTo
  .Logger(lc => lc.Filter
                .ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug)
.WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(path, @"\infolog -{ Date}.txt")))
.CreateLogger();

return log;
}));
```

Then in my controller I inject it

```
MyClass(ILogger ilog){
_ilog = ilog;
}

public void DoSomething(){
this._ilog.Information("logged message");
}
```

I expect to see a log file in the directory called Errorlogs/info-07032021.txt
but nothing is there. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between `{` and `Date}`?

Answer (score -1):

Found it. Path combine only worked when the second argument wasn't an absolute path. So I had to remove the "@"

I had to make it

```
   .WriteTo.RollingFile(path + "\infolog -{ Date}.txt")
```